# roc_auc score GridSearch

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, model-evaluations

I am experimenting with xgboost.

I ran GridSearchCV with score='roc_auc' on xgboost. The best classificator scored ~0.935 (this is what I read from GS output). But now when I run best classificator on the same data:

```
roc_auc_score(Y, clf_best_xgb.predict(X))
```

it gives me score ~0.878

Could you tell me how the score is evaluated in both cases? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **predict_proba** instead of **predict** as below. It should give you the same number.

roc_auc_score(Y, clf_best_xgb.**predict_proba**(X)[:,1])

When we compute AUC, most of time people will use the probability instead of the actual classs.

Comment: Thanks. Also I've slighlty modified it: roc_auc_score(Y, clf_best_xgb.predict_proba(X)[:,1])